# Combining two audiofiles

Tags: java, android, audio

I'm a newbie in java. I tried to play them one by one, but I get an error.
How can I combine two audio files to one? Help me please. It should play different sound if user type different text. I know that between sounds starts should be some pause, but how can I do that. Also can I combine all of sounds for each letter and after that play the whole sound?

```
setContentView(R.layout.main);
    Button bStart = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bStart);
    final EditText etStart = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etStart);
    final EditText etFinish = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etFinish);
    final char[] arr = etStart.getText().toString().toCharArray();
    final MediaPlayer as = MediaPlayer.create(R2d2Activity.this, R.raw.as);
    final MediaPlayer bs = MediaPlayer.create(R2d2Activity.this, R.raw.bs);
    final SoundPool sp;
    final int a;
    sp = new SoundPool(2, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
    a = sp.load(this, R.raw.as, 1);
    bStart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            for (int i=0; i<1; i++){
                String value = etStart.getText().toString();
                String first = value.substring(i, i + 1);
                if(first.contentEquals("a")){
                sp.play(a, 100, 100, 0, 0, 1);
                }if(first.contentEquals("b")){
                sp.play(b, 100, 100, 0, 0, 1);
                }
            }
```

Comment: ask to your designer he will do that one...

Comment: Provide more information please. My first guess is that your problem is that both audiofiles get played at the same time?

Comment: Please clarify your problems. I still don't know you want either to merge 2 audio files or to play different ones successively?

Comment: I don't know how can I pause a progaramm for some time, cause I get an error. But is there a public method or something to link audio  files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Base on your comment, I think you should read SoundPool document:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/SoundPool.html

```
final void pause(int streamID); // Pause a playback stream.
```

It should help you.

---

**edited**:
If you want to force your program to pause all sounds, then you may separate your sound playing to a standalone thread. Just sleep your thread within a period of time.

Comment: it won't help me cuz I want to pause entire programm for the duration of sound. I tried wait(getDuration(sound)); using MediaPlayer but it didn't work